# Google AI Platform Prediction error - Object Detection API models - HttpError 400 - Tensor name has inconsistent batch size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, google-cloud-ml

I need to do remote, on-line predictions using the TensorFlow [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).  I am trying to use the Google AI-Platform.  When I do on-line predictions of Object Detection models on the AI Platform, I get an error similar to:

```
HttpError 400 Tensor name: num_proposals has inconsistent batch size: 1 expecting: 49152
```

When I execute predictions locally (e.g. `result = model(image)`), I get the desired results.

This error occurs for a variety of [Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) models -- Mask-RCNN and MobileNet.  The error occurs on Object Detection models that I have trained, and ones loaded directly from the [Object Detection Model Zoo (v2)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).  I get successful results using the same code, but a model deployed on AI Platform that is not Object Detection.

### Signature Information

The model input `signature-def` seems to be correct:

```
!saved_model_cli show --dir {MODEL_DIR_GS}
!saved_model_cli show --dir {MODEL_DIR_GS} --tag_set serve 
!saved_model_cli show --dir {MODEL_DIR_GS} --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

gives:

```
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:
serve
The given SavedModel MetaGraphDef contains SignatureDefs with the following keys:
SignatureDef key: "__saved_model_init_op"
SignatureDef key: "serving_default"
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_tensor'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_UINT8
      shape: (1, -1, -1, 3)
      name: serving_default_input_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['anchors'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  outputs['box_classifier_features'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (300, 9, 9, 1536)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:1
  outputs['class_predictions_with_background'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (300, 2)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:2
  outputs['detection_anchor_indices'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:3
  outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:4
  outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:5
  outputs['detection_masks'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100, 33, 33)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:6
  outputs['detection_multiclass_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100, 2)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:7
  outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:8
  outputs['final_anchors'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 300, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:9
  outputs['image_shape'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:10
  outputs['mask_predictions'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (100, 1, 33, 33)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:11
  outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:12
  outputs['num_proposals'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:13
  outputs['proposal_boxes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 300, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:14
  outputs['proposal_boxes_normalized'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 300, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:15
  outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 300, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:16
  outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 300, 2)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:17
  outputs['refined_box_encodings'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (300, 1, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:18
  outputs['rpn_box_encodings'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 12288, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:19
  outputs['rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 12288, 2)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:20
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Download a model from [TensorFlow Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).
2. Deploy to AI Platform

```
!gcloud config set project $PROJECT
!gcloud beta ai-platform models create $MODEL --regions=us-central1
```

```
%%bash -s $PROJECT $MODEL $VERSION $MODEL_DIR_GS
gcloud ai-platform versions create $3 \
  --project $1 \
  --model $2 \
  --origin $4 \
  --runtime-version=2.1 \
  --framework=tensorflow \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
  --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4
```

3. Evaluate remotely

```
import googleapiclient
import numpy as np
import socket

img_np = np.zeros((100, 100,3), dtype=np.uint8)
img_list = img_np.to_list()
instances = [img_list]

socket.setdefaulttimeout(600)  # set timeout to 10 minutes
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1', cache_discovery=False, )
model_version_string = 'projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}'.format(PROJECT, MODEL, VERSION)
print(model_version_string)

response = service.projects().predict(
    name=model_version_string,
    body={'instances': instances}
).execute()

if 'error' in response:
    raise RuntimeError(response['error'])
else:    
  print(f'Success.  # keys={response.keys()}')
```

I get an error similar to:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting 
https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gcp_project/models/error_demo/versions/mobilenet:predict?alt=json
returned "{ "error": "Tensor name: refined_box_encodings has inconsistent batch size: 300 
expecting: 1"}}>
```

### Additional Information

- The code fails if I change the `instances` variable in the request body from `instances = [img_list]` to `instances = [{'input_tensor':img_list}]`.
- If I intentionally use an incorrect input shape (e.g. `(1, 100, 100, 2)` or `(100, 100, 2)`, I get a response stating that the input shape is not correct.
- The [Google Cloud Storage JSON Error Code documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#400_Bad_Request) states:

```
invalidArgument -- The value for one of fields in the request body was invalid.
```

- If I repeat this prediction step, I get the same error message, except with different names for tensors.
- If I run the process using `gcloud`

```
import json

x = {"instances":[
[
  [
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0]
  ], 
  [
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0]
  ]
]
]
}
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(x, f)

!gcloud ai-platform predict --model $MODEL --json-request=./test.json
```

I get an `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "{ \"error\": \"Tensor name: anchors has inconsistent batch size: 49152 expecting: 1\" }",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

- I get the same error if I submit the same JSON data above using Google Cloud Console -- the `Test & Use` tab of the AI Platform `Version Details` screen, or the [AI Platform Prediction JSON documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict) on `Method:  Projects.predict`

I enabled logging (both regular and console), but it gives no additional information.

I've placed the details required to reproduce in a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mherzog01/ac835cf7fa87b1109ff47b88d013ed69/ai-platform-prediction-error-object-detection-models.ipynb#scrollTo=5D0eccBESnWi).

Thanks in advance.  I've spent over a day working on this and am really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1047, when the request uses the `instances` key, TensorFlow Serving ensures that all components of the output have the same batch size.  The workaround is to use the `inputs` keyword.

E.g.

```
inputs = [img_list]
...
response = service.projects().predict(
    name=model_version_string,
    body={'inputs': inputs}
```